# How to replace vectors with their sums in a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a [dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ju8nC.png) with hundreds of columns and 30 rows after using the pivot.wider() function. Instead of a vector/array I would like to replace them with their sum, and the NULL values with 0. The only thing I could think of was iterating through the entire dataset and using the sum() function, which I have tried with the code below.

```
for (i in 1:ncol(df))
{
  if is.character(df[,i]) == FALSE
  {
    df[,i] <- sum(df[,i])
  }
}
```

Despite the if statement I still get an "invalid 'type' (character) of argument" error. I am completely new to R so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue would be that while using `pivot_wider`, there are duplicate elements and if we don't specify the `values_fn`, it will return a `list`.  An option is to rerun the `pivot_wider` again and specify the `values_fn`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
mtcars %>% 
     select(gear, mpg, disp) %>% 
     pivot_wider(names_from = gear, values_from = c(mpg, disp), 
           values_fn = list(mpg = ~ sum(., na.rm = TRUE),
                 disp = ~ sum(.,  na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! I am still a bit unsure of what values_fn is; are there duplicate columns that are causing the issue? How do I identify what I should set values_fn to?

Comment: @kiyuhi can you show your original `pivot_wider` code so that it is more clear to me

Comment: wideDf <- pivot_wider(df, names_from = species, values_from = individualCount) where df was a long database with observations as rows and hundreds of columns.

Comment: @kiyuhi In that case, you need `values_fn = list(individualCount = ~sum(., na.rm = TRUE))`